# .animate() c с плавной остановкой

Tags: jquery, animate

К примеру есть `div` c `background-image:url(картинка)` и мы эту картинку сдвигаем с помощью

`$('#div').animate({'background-position': '10px'}, 10000, 'linear');`

Но при сдвиге оно плавно двигает и резко останавливается, как сделать чтобы движение плавно замедлялось а не резко останавливалось?

Comment: почитайте про Easing в animate - это  оно:  An easing function specifies the speed at which the animation progresses at different points within the animation

Comment: Добавь в ответ, помечу галкой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оказывается в .animate() можно указывать тип анимации, т.е чтобы оно в начале разгонялось, а в конце плавно останавливалось код должен быть таким:

```
$('#div').animate({'background-position': '10px'}, 10000, 'swing');
```

Где `swing` это эффект, полный список эффектов можно найти [тут](https://api.jqueryui.com/easings/)